# Казби́ч или Ка́збич?

Tags: орфоэпия

Каково правильное произношение имени одного из героев романа М.Ю. Лермонтова "Герой нашего времени" (Казбич)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Слышал я, что на правом фланге у шапсугов есть какой-то Казбич, удалец, который в красном бешмете разъезжает шажком под нашими выстрелами и превежливо раскланивается, когда пуля прожужжит близко; да вряд ли это тот самый!`

Считается, что в этой фразе говорится о реальной личности - адыге Тугужуко Кызбэче (есть в Википедии). В имени Кызбэч ударение падает на второй слог.

Comment: *В имени Кызбэч ударение падает на второй слог.* — Почему Вы так думаете? (Я не спорю, просто интересно понять, насколько можно доверять Вашему мнению в этом вопросе.)

Comment: Вот тут можете послушать на языке оригинала, с него начинается фильм: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WENEgnKMwWc&t=20s

Comment: Какой вывод вы делаете для ударения в русском варианте имени? В ответе этого нет.

Comment: Мне кажется очевидным, что ударение нужно делать на последнем слоге. Нет сомнений, что Лермонтов слышал это имя на Кавказе и сам произносил его именно с таким ударением.